# makefile for boost sockets

Tags: boost, makefile, boost-asio

I am trying to make my first Makefile for a simple server using boost sockets.

I can get the code to run under windows.

To get it to run under linux I run the command

```
c++ -I /var/boost/boost_1_55_0/ Source.cpp -o source -lboost_system
```

I have a make file 
http://pastebin.com/QTms69Kd

However when I run it I get errors like *undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'*

I got that error before when I forgot the boost_system in  my command. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your `Makefile` looks right and I would normally expect it to work on linux.

You are right to link `boost::system`. The `boost::asio` library is "header only" but it uses the `boost::system` library for error messages, so `boost::system` must be linked into the build.

However, their are a couple of complications with linking boost libraries.
Firstly the location of the library may be necessary in addition to the library itself, e.g.:

```
LDFLAGS := -L/path/to/boost_1_55_0/built_library_directory -lboost_system
```

Secondly, `boost` addd suffixes to the library names to define boost version and possibly the compiler.
So `boost_system` on Windows becomes:

```
libboost_system-vc140-mt-1_60.lib // MSVC 2015, boost 1.60
libboost_system-mgw49-mt-1_60.a   // MinGW, boost 1.60
```

Whilst on a Fedora installation (in /usr/lib64):

```
libboost_system.a
libboost_system.so // symbolic link to: 
libboost_system.so.1.60.0 // gcc, boost 1.60
```

So I think that your issue is not with your `Makefile`, but how you have built the `boost` libraries and where you have put them.

Also, why are you using such an old version of `boost`?

Comment: Probably because I was following an old tutorial. (why boost was old)